# excel show or hide rows based on condition of cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel and i have a macro buttons. The functionalities is Simple.  I have 4 products and their features. What I want to do is, 
Have to buttons that will show all the differences or similarities  - esp since the list is huge.

[image]

So when someone clicks on show similarities, it will show only rows that have same value for example  Row 2, R7,R8, R10, R11
When they click on show differences - R3, R4, R5 and so on.

This is what i tried.

```
Sub BtnShowdifferences_Click()
Dim R As Range("$B$2:$D$11")
For Each row In R.Rows
For Each cell in row.cells
Dim nextcell = cell + 1
If (cell.Value) == (nextcell.Value)  Then
cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
Next
Next
End Sub
```

**How do i check the value of all the cells in the whole row (Excluding the first one).**

Comment: FYI, in VBA, to check if values are equal, it's just one `=`, i.e. `If cell.Value = nextCell.Value Then `....

Comment: No need to use VBA for this. It's possible with an extra column in column E. In E2 you could have something like `=And(b2=c2,c2=d2)`. The results should be `True` (Show Similarities) and `False` (Show Differences).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do i check the value of all the cells in the whole row (Excluding the first one).

Here's a function to do it. It can be used normally or as a UDF as well.

```
Function allCellsEqual(r As Range) As Boolean
  allCellsEqual = Application.CountIf(r, r.Cells(1).Value2) = r.Cells.count
End Function
```

You can use it on each individual row (actual data, not entire-row), and act accordingly. If you don't want to make it a function, you can still use the logic directly in your routine:

```
Dim R As Range, row as Range
Set R = Range("$B$2:$D$11")  '<-- preferably qualify to sheet, i.e. sheet1.Range(...)
For Each row In R.Rows
  ' row.EntireRow.Hidden = Not allCellsEqual(row)
  ' or directly:
    row.EntireRow.Hidden = Application.CountIf(row, row.Cells(1).Value2) <> row.Cells.count
Next
```

This will hide rows with *distinct* values. To hide rows with *equal* values, just use `=` instead of `<>`.

Comment: @A-s-h how doest it exclude the first column?  it always comes up as false.

Comment: @NightMonger it should be preceded by `Dim R As Range: Set R = Range("$B$2:$D$11")`. See edit for more details.

Comment: Before I dive into the deep end to see if all values in a row are equal, can you explain how the `CountIf()` works?  It doesn't seem to loop between all values in the range, just checks if the range has the first value? What if the second or third or `n`th value isn't the same as the others?  (Not saying it doesn't work! Just looking at it confuses me a little).

Comment: @BruceWayne `CountIf(range, criteria)` counts the number of cells that verify the criteria in the range. If the number of cells that are equal to first cell is the total number of cells in the range, then all these cells are equal. :)

Comment: @BruceWayne but of course it shouldn't be used on an *entire row*, just on the range of cells we want to check. As in the answer,  `R = Range("$B$2:$D$11")` so `R.Rows` are the ranges `B2:D2`, `B3:D3`... `B11:D11`.

Comment: Ahaha d'oh, I don't know what I was thinking. I know how `Countif()` works very well... For some reason I thought you'd have to check each value in the countifs...*facepalm*. Good call with that, it's too simple and I was trying to overcomplicate it for no reason.  :thumbsup:

Comment: @A.S.H - Awesome. just the one i was looking for.  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting there, but some syntax is off (like you just need `=` in VBA to compare values).

How does this work?

```
Sub BtnShowdifferences_Click()
Dim R As Range, row As Range
Dim iRow    As Long
Set R = Range("$B$2:$D$11")
For Each row In R.Rows
    If row.row <> R.Rows(1).row Then
        With row
            If .Cells(1) = .Cells(2) And .Cells(2) = .Cells(3) And .Cells(3) = .Cells(1) Then
                row.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next row
End Sub
```

But looking at it, I'm sure there's a quicker/different Non-VBA solution. Perhaps a helper column with a filter?

Comment: is there a way i can check all cells rather than manually entering the value like cell(2) - the reason.. in actually.. the row is very big . i believe it has close to 25 columns..

Comment: @NightMonger - can the values be *anything* or you just want to know if they're all yes or all no?

Comment: They are 4 options  "yes", "No", "N/A" and "TBD". Nothing outside this.